# Object.assign not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ecmascript-6

I have one object called bookings, and inside it I have several properties, and i want extend with Object.assign, like this:

```
let data = Object.assign(booking, {
  hiw: event.hiw[booking.locale],
  tip: event.tip[booking.locale],
  start: moment(event.start).format('L')
});
```

But when I print the data, the result will be the same object from the source (booking), so `hiw`, `tip` and `start` will be ignored, but... if I try to do:

```
let data = Object.assign({}, {
  hiw: event.hiw[booking.locale],
  tip: event.tip[booking.locale],
  start: moment(event.start).format('L')
});
```

This will work perfect.

My question is: what am I doing wrong here? Why can't I extend `booking` and I can extend the empty object?

That's definitely not a problem with async code, when i try to extend booking, he already exist with all properties inside.

I also was trying to use underscore `extend` method, and the behavior is exactly the same.

Comment: Can you show what you have when you print booking just before calling assign and also after?

Comment: This appears to work in Chrome, which (theoretically) uses the same engine as node.js. Are `hiw`, `tip`, or `start` not enumerable or own properties of `booking`? https://jsfiddle.net/mikemccaughan/2959resk/

Comment: I'm wondering if the error is in the `let` block assignment or in the properties you're trying to assign. I put together a very light [mock-up](https://jsfiddle.net/GentleMaN/h10wwo5h/) and it works.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is with the way you assign `booking` before this code.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide more context.

Comment: Is `booking` a simple object, or some sort of class instance (like a Mongoose document)?

Comment: I update the question.

Comment: @robertklep it's a mongoose document.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mongoose documents (model instances) are special: they will only print properties that are present in the schema.

If properties aren't defined there, they won't show up when you `console.log()` them (and also not if you convert the document to a plain JS object with `obj.toObject()`).

This means that using `Object.assign()` will only work if you assign properties that are also present in the schema. Any properties that aren't declared will not be shown (nor saved to the database).

If your intention is to use the document for output, you should convert it to a proper JS object first before assigning to it:

```
let data = Object.assign(booking.toObject(), {
  hiw   : event.hiw[booking.locale],
  tip   : event.tip[booking.locale],
  start : moment(event.start).format('L')
});
```