# Unable to add new property to object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Keeping it simple; I'm unable to add a new property to an object.

I have the following code:

```
function (error, invoice) {
    var date = new Date(+invoice.date);
    var datestamp = date.formatDate('#D##th# #MMM# #YYYY#');
    invoice.datestamp = datestamp;
    console.log(invoice) // <-- no 'datestamp' property
}
```

I have tried various methods such as:

```
Object.defineProperty(invoice, 'datestamp', {value:datestamp});
```

and:

```
invoice[datestamp] = datestamp;
```

All with zero success. I have checked if the `invoice` object is writable using `isSealed()` and `isFrozen()` and indeed it is.

I'm absolutely baffled by this and I feel to have exhaused all alternatives...

Comment: Is `invoice` a proper JS object, or an instance of a class (for instance, a Mongoose document)?

Comment: What is `invoice` ? Why does function not have a name ? How is `function (error, invoice) {` called ? What is `invoice.date` ? Can include `invoice` object at Question ?

Comment: invoice is a proper js object yes and the function is a callback.

Comment: @leaksterrr so where is `invoice` coming from, exactly? What is the posted function a callback for?

Comment: _"invoice is a proper js object yes and the function is a callback."_ Can create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#waterfall

Comment: @leaksterrr I'd think that `async#waterfall` isn't the _source_ of the object, it just passes it around. Is it retrieved from a database, perhaps?

Comment: @robertklep you're right, i've added `.toObject()` where `invoice` is originally created and that's fixed things up.

Comment: @leaksterrr so basically this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364015/object-assign-not-working-as-expected/

Answer (score 0):

I've added `.toObject()` where `invoice` is created and this has resolved my issue.